# function on finite set

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there any function such that

$$ f : A \rightarrow A $$
(A is a finite set, and there exists element 'a' s.t. )
$$  {f}^{n+1}(a)\neq f(a) 
 $$
for any positive interger $n$. ($f^{n+1}$ means $(n+1)$-fold)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\{1,2,3\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3\}$ such that $f(1)=2$, $f(2)=3$ and $f(3)=3$  and $f^{n+1}(1)=3\neq f(1)=2$ for any natural number $n$.

Comment: Simple and clear answer. Thanks.